# Can't select all vertices of circle

Tags: edit-mode

I'm practicing blender 3d v2.79
By the last 3 weeks when get inside the edit mode i can't select the whole circle of vertices by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>left click</kbd>

In the beginning i thought that my laptop keyboard is the problem and i connected an external keyboard and did the same and even my laptop did the same what is the problem

What is the reason, is my short cut wrong 
Give me a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong shortcut, it just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd>. It will select all the vertice lying along its path.

All the best!